# Parameterised NSFetchRequest in iOS 10 returns <uninitialized>

Tags: swift3, ios10

I am migrating my code from swift 2.2 to Swift 2.3, while migrating I realised that in iOS 10, NSFetchRequest is now a parameterised type. Hence I decided to modify my code as below,

```
var fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<SomeEntity>
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                fetchRequest = SomeEntity.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest< SomeEntity>
            } else {
                fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SomeEntity")
            }

            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
            let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let SomeEntityArray = try! appdelegate.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

Now when I ran the code and and put break point on fetchRequest initialisation and printed its description I got "" on executing further code crashes with crash log

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error:
>    is not a valid NSFetchRequest.'

On removing the if condition and keeping it simply

```
var fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<SomeEntity>
fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SomeEntity")
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let SomeEntityArray = try! appdelegate.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

everything works fine!!

Whats the issue with

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                fetchRequest = SomeEntity.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest< SomeEntity>
            }
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any answer?

Comment: @Ranjit : Though not the solution I observed this happens frequently in simulator and works fine on device, not sure is that a bug of iOS or simulator :)  Finally wrapping fetch() or execute in managedObjectContext.perform() or managedObjectContext.performWait() helps stopping crashes as well :)

Comment: You got exact solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which works fine:
`let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Your Entity Name")`

Comment: Use this let request =  NSFetchRequest<Entity Name>(entityName: "Entity Name")